# What effects do Token's of Fidelity/Spite have on summoning/invading and being summoned/invaded?

Tags: dark-souls-2

The game seems to encourage multiplayer more than its predecessors did. When I get summoned and kill a boss successfully I have been given [Token's of Fidelity](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Token+of+Fidelity).

Does having more have any effect on my Summon Sign? Am I more likely to bubble to the top or the bottom? Do I gain any boosts? Or are they purely used for Blue Sentinel sparring matches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a Token of Fidelity while in another players world allows you to heal the host of the world. Having Token of Fidelity in your inventory is also required in order to join the Blue Sentinels covenant.

Having Tokens of Spite in your inventory increases your chances of getting invaded.

Answer (score 2):

The tokens do not turn you human, killing the boss successfully restores humanity.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a token in another player's world while you are hollowed in yours, you also become human again. This is a way to do it if you happen to not have human effigies or if you want to conserve them.

I tested it and I'm 99% sure it was the token that did it

Answer (score 0):

I belive these tokens let you join the Blue Sentinal covenant